# can't sort shopify all blog page

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have created a template and under that, I am assigning 5 categories of blogs but it isn't sorting them all, it is sorting them one by one. can anyone help me with this?

```
 {% assign blog_handles = "skin-care,hair-care,foot-care,sun-care,learn" | split: ","| sort:'published_at' %}
```

{% for handle in blog_handles %}

```
    {% for article in blogs[handle].articles limit: %}
  <div class="blog-articles__article article">
   <div class="card-wrapper underline-links-hover">
     <div class="card article-card card--card article-card__image--medium card--media color-background-1" style="--ratio-percent: 52.33333333333333%;">
    <div class="card__inner  ratio" style="--ratio-percent: 52.33333333333333%;">
      <div class="article-card__image-wrapper card__media">
      <div class="article-card__image media media--hover-effect">
        <img
            srcset="{{ article.image.src | img_url: '533x' }}"
            src="{{ article.image.src | img_url: '533x' }}"
            alt="{{ article.image.src.alt | escape }}"
            class="motion-reduce"
            loading="lazy">
      </div>
    </div>
       </div>
   <div class="card__content">        
        <div class="card__information">
          <h3 class="card__heading h2">
            <a href="{{ article.url }}" class="full-unstyled-link">
              {{ article.title | truncate: 50 | escape }}
            </a>
          </h3>
          <div class="article-card__info caption-with-letter-spacing h5">              
              <span class="circle-divider">{{ article.published_at | time_tag: format: 'date' }}</span>              
          </div>
              <p class="article-card__excerpt rte-width">
                {%- if article.excerpt.size > 0 -%}
                  {{ article.excerpt | strip_html | truncatewords: 30 }}
                {%- else -%}
                  {{ article.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 30 }}
                {%- endif -%}
              </p>            
        </div>

      </div>
     </div>
     </div>
</div>
          
     {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The sort filter should be applied to your loop object which contains the published_at info (your handle list doesn't).

Something like that (not tested) should work:

```
{% assign articles = blogs[handle].articles | sort:'published_at' %}
{% for article in articles %}
    Do something
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No! it isn't working, It is showing the same result as before.

Comment: Mmh. When you display {{ article.published_at }} without formatting, which value do you get?

Comment: yeah, it is showing the date, time & timezone.

Comment: My main issue is, that it is calling the category's value one by one, Like I have 5 categories, then it shows data of 1st-2nd-so on. It does not sort them all at once.

Comment: do you have any solution for that issue? @AliceGirard